# Adjustable bars connected as a group, value in textfields

Tags: javascript

I want 5 bars that are connected in the way that the total value of hem is 100%

ex user moves bar 1 up 4% and bar 2,3,4,5 moves down 1% each.

the values should be projected in textfields so the form can be POSTed for some PHP operations.

I have seen this on webapplications before and just assume it is javascript. does anone know how it is done?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Those "bars" are usually called "sliders". Most popular libraries have a class for such control. Here's a slider, I've written once: http://www.zavoevately.ru/js/slider.js You can use it, if you're not going to directly sell parts of this code.
It requires Mootools for some functions, but works in quirksmode and have "cut" feature:
E.g. you have a scale from 0 to 100, but values only from 0 to 50 should be chosen. It will be useful for some combinations of values for several bound sliders.

You'll need to call `setValue` for all sliders except that one, in which it was called in order to keep their values bound.

> the values should be projected in
>   textfields

just add code which will update textfield into change function — change property in third argument in constructor. Also may will need a nethod for updatind `_max_cut` and `_min_cut` and re-initializing all dependant values.

You may do the similar thing with YUI slider, which is more popular, versatile and is supported =)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if YUI slider works with this multiple function I need. I.e. that they affect eachother in the sense that they have a collctive total value?

Comment: No, you'll need to create your own function, which will update remaining sliders after the change of one of them. YUI slider is better, cause it allows to update its value w/o firing change event and performing recursive onChange calls. Maybe slider from some other frameworks allow that.